# how to install p2os in ros (groovy version) in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-groovy, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've installed groovey version in my os (ubuntu 12.10), i want to test my navigation algorithm for my project in a mobile robot, so i select gazebo simulator and pioneer3dx, but when i want to use this command for groovy(sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-p2os) i got this error (E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-p2os), what should i do?! i think this stack is not available for groovy version, is it correct ?

Thank you so much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60611/how-to-install-p2os-in-ros-(groovy-version)-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the new p2os repository for Groovy!

```
git clone https://github.com/allenh1/p2os
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-20**:
Hi allenh1,
I cloned from ur source. then when i run $rosrun p2os_dashboard p2os_dashboard i get rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: robot_monitor. I did source for both path (opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash and catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash). Please help. I'm stuck here.

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-20**:
when i run $ rosrun p2os_teleop p2os_teleop _port:=/dev/ttyUSB1
[ INFO] [1382433617.280646919]: deadman_button: 0
[ INFO] [1382433617.281032583]: run_button: 0
if i run $roslaunch p2os_launch teleop_keyboard.launch then it gives instruction to move robot but robot doesn't respond.

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-21**:
Hi Allenh1, I manage to overcome that.but now when i run $rosrun p2os_dashboard p2os_dashboard i get ImportError: No module named msg. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use ROSAIRA instead of p2os, which is unavailable in groovy and has been broken for quite some time.

Here is a tutorial that I give my students for getting ROS running on a P3AT, it should be a similar process for a DX, just change the URDF:

http://goo.gl/kQEyA

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-06-07**:
p2os isn't broken anymore! Even the URDF is working.